# java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind - when stating tomcatx with jdk1.8 (not in debug mode)

Tags: java, tomcat, nio, java-8

While setting up an environment for a tomcat project I ran into the exception

```
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
```

The message is clear: the port is already used by some other process. So to troubleshoot I ran the following command

```
 netstat -aon | find "<port>"
```

which returned nothing and thus suggests that the port is free for use by a new process.

Here is my statup script for tomcat, note here the use of the jdk `1.8` as `JAVA_HOME`

```
@ECHO OFF
@SET JAVA_HOME=C:\Oracle\java\jdk1.8
@SET CATALINA_HOME=C:\<project>\apache-tomcat-8.0
@SET JAVA_OPTS=-Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m
@CALL %CATALINA_HOME%\bin\catalina.bat run
```

At first I though it was an issue with tomcat8, so I have tryied with `7` and `6` too. Same issue.

After that, I stated to suspect the jdk, so I changed to `1.7`

```
@SET JAVA_HOME=C:\Oracle\java\jdk1.7
```

and the problem was gone, with the same port numbers and the three tomcats.

So I checked my version of the jdk

```
Cmd-$> %JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe -version
java version "1.8.0"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0-b132)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.0-b70, mixed mode)
```

and did an update (uninstall+install) to the latest version (at posting time)

```
Cmd-$> %JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe -version
java version "1.8.0_05"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_05-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.5-b02, mixed mode)
```

So my questions are:

1. Am I mistaken somewhere and is there anything else I could check?
2. Is this a bug in the oracle's jdk 1.8, and if yes is there a workaound for this?

If there is any other informations I should provide, please comment.

**EIDT**

Running the sample code in the bug report referenced by @StephenC fails on the first time with jdk `1.8` and behaves as one would expect with my actual jdk version of `1.7`.

```
Cmd-$> %JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe -version
java version "1.7.0_17"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_17-b02)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.7-b01, mixed mode)
```

i.e. the first run is ok and the server responds correctly, the second fails with the expected `BindExcxeption`.

The 1.7 jdk which presumably reproduces the bug according to the bug report is

```
java version "1.7.0_05"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_05-b05)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.1-b03, mixed mode)
```

Running Tomcat 7 from eclipse using the [Sysdeo Eclipse Tomcat Launcher plugin](http://www.eclipsetotale.com/tomcatPlugin.html) gave no BindException, here are my setting for the plugin

[image]

I noticed though that the plugin runs `javaw.exe` not `java.exe`. I can't tell whether it makes a difference of not.

Note that the tomxcat is ran in `debug` mode (the checkbox `Don't run Tomcat in debug mode` is not checked). If not ran in debug mode the exception comes.

Also runnig tomcat from the script in debug mode using the `jpda` switch

```
@CALL %CATALINA_HOME%\bin\catalina.bat jpda run
```

seems to work around this issue.

**UPDATE**

Test on a 32 bit machine (+ 32 bit jdk and tomcat) were all successful with both jdk 1.8 and 1.7. Also the test class from the bug report behaves normally, i.e. BindException on second run.

**UPDATE 2**

The issue has survived a computer restart. Here is the output of the start process including the stacktrace, all other ports (AJP on 10009 and the server itself on 10005) are bound correctly:

```
Cmd-$> starttc.bat
Using CATALINA_BASE:   "C:\<project>\apache-tomcat-8.0"
Using CATALINA_HOME:   "C:\<project>\apache-tomcat-8.0"
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "C:\<project>\apache-tomcat-8.0\temp"
Using JRE_HOME:        "C:\workspaces\Oracle\jdk1.8"
Using CLASSPATH:       "C:\<project>\apache-tomcat-8.0\bin\bootstrap.jar;C:\<project>\apache-tomcat-8.0\bin\tomcat-juli.jar"
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=128m; support was removed in 8.0
05-May-2014 09:16:08.043 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.init The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\workspaces\Oracle\jdk1.8\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\workspaces\Oracle\jdk1.6\bin;C:\oracle\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\bin;C:\workspaces\Databases\oracle\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Window
s\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Novell\ZENworks\bin;C:\Program Files\SlikSvn\bin;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\bin;C:\Program Files\SlikSvn\bin;C:\private\bin;C:\Oracle\jdk1.6\bin;C:\MinGW\bin;C:\Misc\c_c++\process builder;C:\Apache\apache-maven-3\bin;C:\tools\database\sqlite\bin;.
05-May-2014 09:16:08.374 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-10090"]
05-May-2014 09:16:08.399 SEVERE [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Failed to initialize end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-10090"]
 java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:414)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:406)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:214)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:351)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:683)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:456)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol.init(AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol.java:120)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:960)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:567)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:826)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:605)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:630)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:310)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:484)

05-May-2014 09:16:08.402 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal Failed to initialize connector [Connector[HTTP/1.1-10090]]
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-10090]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:106)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:567)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:826)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:605)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:630)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:310)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:484)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler initialization failed
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:962)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
        ... 12 more
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:414)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:406)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:214)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:351)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:683)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:456)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol.init(AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol.java:120)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:960)
        ... 13 more

05-May-2014 09:16:08.404 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-10009"]
05-May-2014 09:16:08.453 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
05-May-2014 09:16:08.456 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 797 ms
05-May-2014 09:16:08.484 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service Catalina
05-May-2014 09:16:08.484 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.5
05-May-2014 09:16:08.494 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory C:\<project>\apache-tomcat-8.0\webapps\docs
05-May-2014 09:16:08.951 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGenerator.createSecureRandom Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [151] milliseconds.
05-May-2014 09:16:08.985 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory C:\<project>\apache-tomcat-8.0\webapps\examples
05-May-2014 09:16:09.786 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory C:\<project>\apache-tomcat-8.0\webapps\host-manager
05-May-2014 09:16:09.828 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory C:\<project>\apache-tomcat-8.0\webapps\manager
05-May-2014 09:16:09.883 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory C:\<project>\apache-tomcat-8.0\webapps\ROOT
05-May-2014 09:16:09.916 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-10009"]
05-May-2014 09:16:09.937 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 1489 ms
05-May-2014 09:17:30.430 INFO [Thread-5] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.pause Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-10090"]
05-May-2014 09:17:30.431 INFO [Thread-5] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.pause Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-10009"]
05-May-2014 09:17:30.498 INFO [Thread-5] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.stopInternal Stopping service Catalina
05-May-2014 09:17:30.551 INFO [Thread-5] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.stop Stopping ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-10009"]
05-May-2014 09:17:30.589 INFO [Thread-5] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.stop Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-10090"]
05-May-2014 09:17:30.589 INFO [Thread-5] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-10090"]
05-May-2014 09:17:30.590 INFO [Thread-5] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-10009"]
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you have been bitten by a Java 8 bug fix!

http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7179799

Java on Linux and other (non-Windows) operating systems has always thrown an exception if you attempt to bind to a port that is already bound.  For some reason, this was allowed in Java 6 and 7 on some Windows platforms.  Oracle have deemed this to be a bug, and fixed it.

Presumably, you were running 3 instances of Tomcat all listening on the same port as a "poor man's" load balancer.  You are going to need to find another, more reliable way to do this.

---

**UPDATE**

Just to make it clear, you should not *attempt* to run two Tomcat instances on the same port.  Especially a production server and a test server.

If you do manage to get it "working", then it will be uncertain which instance will get requests sent to the IP/port.  Some may go to the production server, and some to the test server.  In short, your test server will *interfere* with your production server.

A much better idea is to configure your test Tomcat instance to listen on a different port and/or IP address to the production instance.

Comment: Nope, no load balancing attempt, just one single instance for test purpose.

Comment: Well that's easy then.  Just don't do it :-)  Change the test Tomxat's port, or run the test Tomcat on a different machine.

Comment: This happened on my dev machine (64 bit), no production environment and no other tomcats or whatsoever running. As I said in my EDIT, tomcat starts properly with the same ports when in debug mode (which makes it even stranger). As far as I could test on my 32 bit personal computer, everything works fine.

Comment: It really doesn't matter whether this is a dev machine, a production machine, or whatever.  The solution is the same.  Don't do it.  Two Tomcats listening on the same IP/port *should* fail, and if it doesn't fail it won't work properly ... unless you've designed it to work that way.

Comment: This idea has never crossed my mind, one cannot have one door to two different houses ;-)

Answer (score 3):

I have the impression that **find** does not work as expected. Try:

```
netstat -aon | findstr "80"
```

or just

```
netstat -aon
```

to make sure that port 80 is free

Comment: I have redirected the output to a text file and searched it with notepad++, I have also used the command with port which was present in the output and it was found.

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat uses more than one port. You're just assuming that port 80 is the problem. Have a look through server.xml and check *all* the ports mentioned. Your Tomcat may be running on port 8080 for example, or it may be the shutdown port, which is normally 8005, or the HTTPS port (443 or 8443), ...

Comment: I don't have the stack trace right now but I am pretty sure the port that could not be bound is part of the error message, and that's the one I looked for. Also, if that was the case then it would not bind successfully in debug mode. The sample code from the bug report StephenC mentioned also runs successfully when using the debug launcher and fails when using the normal launcher in eclipse.

Comment: In that case you shouldn't have posted an incomplete error message.

Comment: Basically you're right, I just thought I could spare that since this exception from tomcat is well known and there are many other question on here about this case. The problems is strange anyways and the jdk might not be the cause, I'll try to reproduce it again on Monday, maybe a restart of my machine would have fixed it, in that I'll just close the question.